# Expectation Value of a Potential Using Radial Solution of Hydrogen Atom

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, physics

I am trying to input $R_{nl}$, which is the radial solution of the hydrogen atom and I would like to obtain an expectation value of particular potential. This is my code:

```
R[n_, l_, r_] := 
  Sqrt[4*Z^3*((n - l - 1)!/(Subscript[a, \[Mu]]^3*n^4*(n + l)!))]*
   Exp[(-Z)*(r/(n*Subscript[a, \[Mu]]))]*(2*Z*(r/(n*Subscript[a, \[Mu]])))^
    l*LaguerreL[n - l - 1, 2*l + 1, 2*Z*(r/(n*Subscript[a, \[Mu]]))]
```

This is the integration I would like to perform:

```
 FullSimplify[Integrate[r^2*R[n, l, r]^2*(Exp[(-s)*(r - R) - 1]/r), 
   {r, R, Infinity}], Assumptions -> 
   {n, l, R, Z, s, Subscript[a, \[Mu]]}*\[Epsilon]*Positive]
```

Mathematica only returns the input for me. Any suggestions that I can fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started, 1) take the introductory [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that your code uses $R$ as both a function and a constant in the potential and in the limits of integration.  Also, the `*ϵ*Positive` doesn't do what you want it to do.  Further, MMA usually is not able to perform symbolic integration with functions like `LaguerreL`.  We must usually give numeric values for $n, l$.

For the ground state, we could write

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

ψr[n_, l_, r_] := 
 Sqrt[4*Z^3*((n - l - 1)!/(Subscript[a, μ]^3*n^4*(n + l)!))]*
  Exp[(-Z)*(r/(n*Subscript[a, μ]))]*(2*
     Z*(r/(n*Subscript[a, μ])))^l*
  LaguerreL[n - l - 1, 2*l + 1, 2*Z*(r/(n*Subscript[a, μ]))]

With[{n = 1, l = 0},
 Integrate[r^2*ψr[n, l, r]^2*(Exp[(-s)*(r - R) - 1]/r),
  {r, R, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {0 < {Subscript[a, μ], Z, s}}]
 ]
```

$$\frac{4 Z^3 e^{-\frac{2 R Z}{a_{\mu
   }}-1} \left(a_{\mu } (R s+1)+2 R
   Z\right)}{a_{\mu }^2 \left(s a_{\mu
   }+2 Z\right){}^2}$$